# How to embed .mp4 videos in a WordPress post?

Tags: plugins, videos, embed

I want to embed a video that was converted to mp4 from wmv, using ffmpeg. The video of course plays fine in VLC. However, it's being quite a pain to embed it in a WP post.

I've tried using a variety of plugins -

1. Simple Flash Video - This plugin almost works. The thumbnail of the video is shown, and on click a ShadowBox appears with the JW Player loading the video inside. However, thats as far as it goes - the video never begins playing. The important thing here is, my download manager - FlashGet - shows that it can intercept the video being loaded. This means that at least the correct video URL is used here.
2. Flash Video Player - doesnt respond at all.
3. FLxER Player.

Any pointers here ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post on how to do this a while back. Might help.

http://ottopress.com/2011/howto-html5-video-that-works-almost-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

I always just write the HTML code to "embed" the video. Do a Google search on the phrase "html embed video" and you'll find lots of examples on what you need to write within the opening and closing embed tags (you'll want to edit the page in "source" view mode, not the "WYSIWYG" mode).

Answer (score 0):

I use [VideoJS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) and it works like a charm. Also adds HTML5 cool-ness!

Comment: didnt work.. the video doesnt load at all..

Comment: Can you explain the problem? any errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Simple download Handbrakes at https://handbrake.fr/ and then encode the desired video, you can still upload same mp4 format and convert to mp4 "encoded" format. It would require a name and a desired location to be saved. Once done, drag and drop your encoded video and then, copy and paste the link on the desired page, you're good to go.